# Seeing ORA-01858 a Non numeric character was found?

Tags: sql, oracle

this is for oracle sql developer the following is my query

```
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENTS (DATE,PARTNER_NAME,ENROLLMENTS)
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM') AS DATE, mrch_bnft_cd, COUNT(*)
    FROM ENROLLMENTS 
    WHERE TS > trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + 5/24 
    AND TS < trunc(sysdate, 'HH') + 5/24
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM'), mrch
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM'), mrch_bnft
```

I get an error

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected error
```

but the error is not telling me where. Any ideas?

```
DATE = TIMESTAMP(6)
TS = TIMESTAMP(6)  
PARTNER = VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)  
ENROLLMENTS = NUMBER  
MRCH_BNFT= VARCHAR2(35 BYTE)
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again; if you aren't happy with the answers you got before, improve your question and provide any additional information you were asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly suspicious:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TS, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH AM') AS DATE
```

Why are you converting the a `timestamp` to a string to put into a field called `date`?  If you want the date down to a particular hour, use `TRUNC()` instead:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TS, 'HH')
```

So:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TS, 'HH') AS DATE, mrch_bnft_cd, COUNT(*)
FROM ENROLLMENTS 
WHERE TS > trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + 5/24 AND
      TS < trunc(sysdate, 'HH') + 5/24
GROUP BY TRUNC(TS, 'HH'), mrch
ORDER BY TRUNC(TS, 'HH'), mrch_bnft;
```

I would also recommend `+ interval '5' hour` rather than the date arithmetic, but your version is actually fine.

Comment: thank you so much this fixed it.